# Want to print string in order but now what to use while using scanner class Compiling it is giving an error.?

Tags: java

```
import java.util.*;
class Stringord
{

public static void main(String...s)

{

String name[] = new String[6];

Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("Enter 6 Letter Word ?");

for(int i=0;i<6;i++)

{

name[i]=sc.nextString();

}

for(int i=0;i<6;i++)

{

System.out.println(name[i]);

}

}

}
```

Comment: Are you asking _us_ if it is giving an error? Or are you telling us there is an error without telling us which _specific_ error it is? In either case, you're doing it wrong and should read the Help Center.

Comment: Can you give us a link to the Scanner.nextString() method in the API?

Comment: At least format and indent your code.

Comment: You are also asking for a single 6 letter word. Then (assuming you use next() which will return the next word ) when you get to the second word which is non existent you're going to get an error message

Answer (score 1):

There's no such thing as `Scanner#nextString()`. Use [`sc.next()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next--) for a token, or [`sc.nextLine()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine--) for a full line.

Answer (score 0):

Use nextLine not nextString

```
   for(int i=0;i<6;i++)

    {

    name[i]=sc.nextLine();

    }
```